# I cannot modify an HTML element via CSS once a javascript function is applied to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I created the following DIV element with css properties:

html:

```
<div id="transparentdiv">
this is a div
</div>
```

css:

```
#transparentdiv
{
height: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
transition: all 1.25s;
width: 0px;
}
```

next I have the following javascript modify the div when the user clicks a button:

```
transparentdiv.style.borderRadius="20px";
transparentdiv.style.boxShadow="-6px -6px 6px blue, 6px -6px 6px blue, 
                                      -6px 6px 6px blue, 6px 6px 6px blue";
transparentdiv.style.backgroundColor="black";
transparentdiv.style.display="block";
transparentdiv.style.height="80%";
transparentdiv.style.left="10%";
transparentdiv.style.opacity="0.9";
transparentdiv.style.top="10%";
transparentdiv.style.width="80%";
```

once the DIV is modified by the javascript, I can no longer modify the DIV using css. the only thing I can seem to do is delete the div using javascript. any idea what is happening here? I have all of the code if needed. it is a long script.

Comment: transparentdiv what is this where you initializing it ?

Comment: How are you attempting to modify the div via CSS after your javascript interaction?

Comment: what do you mean by "I can no longer modify DIV using css" . what modification ?

Comment: transparentdiv is the ID of the DIV element, noted in the HTML section.

Comment: I created another function to edit the DIV after clicking on a 2nd button. No CSS seems to work on it. height, width, opacity, display:none, nothing...

Comment: Please use `document.getElementById('transparentdiv')` when referencing. Straight up ID reference is outdated and might cause issues.

Comment: Try setting up an example that demonstrates the issue (at jsFiddle or similar). Otherwise we can only guess at what you are doing.

Comment: yeah I tried that also. still nothing. the weird part is, the actual javascript commands work on it. Just not css that is changed by javascript.

Comment: here we go. I put all the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FuZx8/1/

Comment: Javascript is adding inline styles to your html. No amount of CSS will override that. What you could try take all those styles out of your javascript and put in a new CSS class, called "active" or whatever. Then use js to apply and remove that class to your div.

Comment: oh wow. how dumb am I? I used setinterval instead of settimeout! of course it is reverting any changes that I make. thanks guys. I feel like a bonehead. time to hang it up for the night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add

```
var transparentdiv = document.getElementById('transparentdiv');
```

In your javascript function

Working example **[here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ftrukqm7)**

Comment: I am confused why you need to tell javascript to address the element by ID. I thought I was doing that by saying "elementname.style.whatever". It doesn't know what you mean I guess?

Comment: @DouglasLandmesser so that means my solution solved your issue?

Comment: yes, that corrected the issue. I guess javascript didn't know how to address the DIV without using the getelementbyid piece.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify `DIV` using CSS `!important` property which overwrite the inline `css` which is generated by Javascript like this:-

```
#transparentdiv{background:#FFF !important;
```